# OPCUA subscribing to all events

Tags: opc, opcode, siemens, honeywell, unified-automation-sdk

I want to get all events when subscribing to server object at UA Expert, for that how can I listen to the Server object.

I am using prosys JAVA sdk 4.2.0
As of now when I am subscribing directly to the specific sub-objects node of server object, I am able to get the events. But need to get all events also when subscribing to only server object node.
And what code I need to implement at my side. If someone can please help.